# Does wxRuby run with Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, wxruby

I am investigating cross-platform GUI toolkits with Ruby bindings.

wxRuby appears to be a pretty good one, but I am wondering if it has bindings for Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work with 1.9.2, but you have to install it this way

```
gem install wxruby-ruby19
```

Otherwise, it will not work on 1.9.2. I'm on 1.9.2 and it took me quite awhile to figure that out how to get it installed correctly. Anyways, I have used it and think that it is pretty good, although I had not used any other GUI frameworks in Ruby.